# Call sequence of viewWillDisappear of the previous controller and viewWillAppear of the next controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I wanted to know what is the correct sequence of method calls for viewWillDisappear of the previous controller and viewWillAppear of the next controller? I see sometime when we go from first view controller to second, viewWillAppear of second view controller will be called first and then the viewWillDisappear of the first view controller. And at times it is reverse.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the same experience. Also this is different in ios4.x vs iOS5.x I found. So I ended up assuming that there is no pre-defined order.

Even worse when there is an AlertView involved....

Anyway, could you please explain why does it matter in your case?

Assuming you need to pass some kind of variable or textView content  you might do in an extended

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil withMyData:....
```